# Python: mechanize has no attribute 'TextControl' error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, command-line, mechanize

I am using Python code which was written one year ago.

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10 with Python 2.6.6.

The code snippet is:

```
import mechanize
.....
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['sign_in[email]'] = username
br['sign_in[password]'] = password
tc = mechanize.TextControl('hidden', 'token', {'value':token})
tc.add_to_form(br.form)
self.submit()
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextControl'

What is wrong? Whats the original author's intention here? When I google `TextControl`, nothing seems to be related with mechanize. I install mechanize by `apt-get install python-mechanize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it would appear that the version of mechanize you've got installed is not the correct version for the code you're attempting to run.

This source:

https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/__init__.py

suggests that `TextControl` should be present (although it's deprecated).

I suggest you remove python-mechanize (using apt), and instead use a newer copy of mechanize by using easy_install (or download and install from source).

Of course, if you've got other packages installed which are relying on the older version of mechanize, you're probably better off getting the source, and loading the module from this.

Comment: HI Is there a way to see which version of mechanize that I am using now?

Comment: @SusanMayer: `import mechanize; mechanize.__version__` will return the version you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not working with the same version of the `mechanize` library. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/__init__.py) in github, I see this in `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = [
    ...
    'TextControl',
    'TextareaControl',
   ]
```

So certainly there should be some `TextControl` somewhere. In the github version is actually defined in [`_form.py`](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_form.py).